# Is there a eslint rule for warning me about comparing uninitialized boolean variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, eslint

Consider the following code:

```js
const onData = (value: boolean | undefined, cb: (data: boolean) => void) => {
    if (value) {
        cb(value);
    }
}
```

Obviously, `cb` will execute on truthy values. However if `value === false` then `cb` won't be executed. This problem gets even worse when value can be a `number`, `string` etc. and have a falsy value (`0`, `""` respectively).
While this is certainly just an inaccuracy in programming (I should compare `value === undefined`), I cannot count how many times I traced a bug in an application down to this exact problem.

Is there an eslint rule that will warn me when I do not compare a variable with a type that can have a falsy value (`null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, `false`, `NaN`) on the line where I check for the truthiness?

Something like:

```js
const onData = (value: boolean | undefined, cb: (data: boolean) => void) => {
    if (value) { // <--- eslint warn: Compare with value instead of checking truthiness
        cb(value);
    }
}
```

Same for `value: string`, `value: number`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for `"@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions": "error"`

https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/strict-boolean-expressions/

The following will fail the lint:

```
// nullable numbers are considered unsafe by default
let num: number | undefined = 0;
if (num) {
  console.log('num is defined');
}

// nullable strings are considered unsafe by default
let str: string | null = null;
if (!str) {
  console.log('str is empty');
}

// nullable booleans are considered unsafe by default
function foo(bool?: boolean) {
  if (bool) {
    bar();
  }
}

// `any`, unconstrained generics and unions of more than one primitive type are disallowed
const foo = <T>(arg: T) => (arg ? 1 : 0);

// always-truthy and always-falsy types are disallowed
let obj = {};
while (obj) {
  obj = getObj();
}
```